# Data not pulling through on Magento Dashboard e.g. lifetime sales and charts

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm using **Magento 1.9.3.0**

The problem is that Lifetime sales and charts in dashboard are not displaying any information, the only value that is displayed is **£0.00**.

I've placed orders and there's still nothing. I've also enabled charts in

```
System > Configuration > Admin > Dashboard > Enable Charts
```

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Reports->Refresh Statistics, select all the items in the grid, select from the top right dropdown "Refresh Lifetime statistics" and hit submit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried what you suggested but it's still showing no data. I've even marked orders as 'Completed', thinking that could be wrong but unfortunately, it's showing no data. Do you have any other suggestions please?